# rndc fails to add zone, bind99 freebsd

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, freebsd, nameserver

I solved all rndc key errors and appear to perform most functions but when testing the addzone feature I am getting this error while trying to use rndc to add a fresh new zone ->

```
rndc addzone validdomain.com  '{type master; file "/usr/local/etc/namedb/validdomain.com.validzone";};'

rndc: 'addzone' failed: not found
```

I have no errors in my logs.
How do I add a valid zone via rndc?

Comment: Is the  `allow-new-zones` option  set to yes in your named.conf and is that directory writeable for the nameserver?

Comment: @HBruijn  yes, 'allow-new-zones yes;' is set in options

Comment: Is your master zone file exists ?

Comment: I suspect you're not actually using the rndc *client* that ships with bind99. This is a fairly common mistake. Double check the version output of the client just to be safe. Even if the correct package is installed, use `which rndc` and verify that it's not being overridden by another one in your path.

Comment: @krisFR  yes, validdomain.com.validzone is a valid zone.

Comment: @AndrewB I am not sure, I chose the defaults  ->   # pkg info |grep bind
bind99-9.9.6P1_3               BIND DNS suite with updated DNSSEC and DNS64  (freebsd)

Comment: @krisFR  sample valid zone that the command will fail on  https://bpaste.net/show/7037f965d3ab , I have many zones that look exactly like this one.

Comment: What is the output of `rndc -? 2>&1 | tail -1`?

Comment: @AndrewB  Version: 9.9.6-P1

Comment: @AndrewB  I just upgraded to 9.10, the output is now ->  Version: 9.10.2

Comment: same issue with 9.10 even adjustments in make config  http://i.imgur.com/MA5WP5e.png   :(